# Linking Fragments With Buttons

Tags: android

Can someone please help me?
i just want to add 2 Buttons in a activity and each button goes to a different fragment
for example:
Button 1 goes to Login_Fragment
Button 2 goes to SignUp_Fragment
those fragments have their own xml files
the code below is FirstPage and it's xml is first_page 
so the below code will replace the first_page xml with the fragments xml files
how can i prevent that?

```
package com.example.logindesign;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

public class First_Page extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button createAccount, login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_page);



        createAccount = findViewById(R.id.createAccount);
        createAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                SignUp_Fragment f2 = new SignUp_Fragment();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mParent, f2).commit();
            }
        });


        login = findViewById(R.id.login);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                Login_Fragment f2 = new Login_Fragment();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.mParent, f2).commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Blue"
    android:id="@+id/mParent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stay_connected_with_friends"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        >

    </TextView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/createAccount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/Blue"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="172dp"
        android:background="@color/Blue"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp">

    </Button>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="141dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="114dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="136dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />





</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please, add some code to complete your question. You can find info and tips about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: here you go i hope you understand what i want to accomplish :)

Answer (score 1):

use code like this,
 click on button A,

```
 Fragment A = new FragmentA();
```

click on button B,

```
Fragment B = new FragmentB();
```

and make a function for both load Fragments,

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment f)
 {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_contenier,f).commit();
 }
```

Comment: i would still have to add or replace a layout. ok so i have an activity which has 2 buttons A & B, A goes to firstFragment, B goes to secondFragment, but the problem is when i put .replace(R.id.container, f) activity layout is overlapping with the firsFragment layout, and the secondFragment layout, i want to avoid that.

Comment: use this code,     
public function loadFragment(Fragment f)
 {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().remove(fm.findFragmentById(R.id.main_contenier)).add(R.id.main_contenier,f).commit();
 }

Comment: but i'm getting a lot of errors from that code, cannot resolve symbol function, and loadFragment is never used, and f cannot resolve symbol f, it'd be very helpful if you posted how the whole code should work, really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use FragmentManager
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager?hl=en
and use tags to determine how the navigation flows

```
class MainMenuFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager
```

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        viewFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu_fragment, container, false)
        supportFragmentManager = activity!!.supportFragmentManager

        val buttonDocumentList: Button = viewFragment.findViewById(R.id.btn_menu_top_left)
        buttonDocumentList.setOnClickListener {
            replaceFragment(
                DocumentListFragment.newInstance(), "${FragmentTypes.DOCUMENT_LIST}"
            )
        }
```

```
    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, tag: String) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_activity_container, fragment, tag)
            .commitNow()
    }
```